# CSS Position relative goes over fixed how to fix this?

Tags: html, css

Basically after doing research i found out that the only way fro the text in a text box to start from the bottom and go up without overflowing down is to set position absolute and relative.

But by doing so it goes over my fixed nav bar.

Any way to fix this issue?

```
#ChatName{
    width: 99%;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;

}
#ContentWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
#ChatBig {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    height: 600px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
    resize:none;
    position: relative;

}
#ChatMessages{
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 55px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    resize:none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;

}
#ChatText{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    resize:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;

}
#ChatText:focus{outline: none;}

#RightContent{
    width: 25%;
    height: 600px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#Online{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;

}
#IsOnline{
    width: 100%;
    height: 24px;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
}
#IsActive{
    width: 100%;
    height: 24px;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;

}
body {
    background-color: #edf0f5;
}
#Holder {
    width: 100%;
}
.UserNameS{
    color: #7CB9E8;
}
.UserNameS:hover{text-decoration:underline; cursor: pointer;}
#nav{
    width:100% !important;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px gray;
    position:fixed;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow: hidden;

    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#UserNav{
    float: right;
    width: 33%;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#CreteChat{
    width: 33%;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;

}
#Logo{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height:50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#ChatCreate {
    width: 300px;

}
#Wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 720px;
}
```

[image]

and i want it to be like this

[image]

but when its like this look how my text bar disappears and texts goes blow the box border

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first guess is to give `#ChatText` a `z-index` value, maybe -1.

Comment: Thank you, that worked.. will give you a + in 3 min when it lets me

Comment: Um.. actually.. now i cannot click on any of the divs... means i cannot write in chat

Comment: sorted it, dont worry

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but Marc's answer may be an issue if you've got numerous things in your body and want your nav to stay on top, so it's better to give the `#nav` a high `z-index` (like `100`) instead.